# setToolbar() method throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to the android and creating a navigation drawer using `NavigationView` and getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`. First there is a splash screen and after few seconds there will be a `Home Activity` which will have `Navigation Drawer`.

**SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
 package com.zenica.app.zenica;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;    
    import android.app.ActivityOptions;    
    import android.content.Context;    
    import android.content.Intent;   
    import android.os.Build;   
    import android.os.Bundle;   
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;   
    import android.transition.Explode;   
    import android.transition.Transition;   
    import android.view.Window;   
    import android.os.Handler;

    @TargetApi(21)
        public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

        private static final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000; // time out for the splash in ms
    private Handler mHandlerSplash;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int currentapiVersion= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if(currentapiVersion== Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Transition ts = new Explode();
            ts.setStartDelay(2000);
            //set the duration
            ts.setDuration(5000);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts);
            //set an exit transition so it is activated when the current activity exits
            getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_main_activity);
            launchSecondActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_main_activity);
            mContext = this;
            mHandlerSplash = new Handler();
            mHandlerSplash.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                    finish();
                }},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
    }

    public void launchSecondActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
    }

}
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
  package com.zenica.app.zenica;    

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;        
    import android.os.Build;   
    import android.os.Bundle;   
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;   
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;   
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;   
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;    
    import android.transition.Slide;    
    import android.transition.Transition;    
    import android.view.Menu;    
    import android.view.MenuItem;    
    import android.view.Window;    

    /**
     * Created by Neha on 03-02-2016.
     */        
     public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Toolbar mtoolar;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    private NavigationView navView;
    @TargetApi(21)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int currentapiVersion= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentapiVersion== Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Transition ts = new Slide();
            ts.setDuration(3000);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);
          //  setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        }
        else
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //   setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        }
        setToolbar();
        setNavigationDrawer();

     /*   result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mtoolar)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Home".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(1).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("New Cars".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(2).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Book A Test Drive".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(3).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Our Locations".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(4).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Sell A Car".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(5).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Pay Bills".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(6).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("About Zenica".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(7).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Connect".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(8).withCheckable(true),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("About App".toUpperCase()).withIdentifier(9).withCheckable(true) )
        .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                if (drawerItem != null) {
                    if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                        //switchFragment(new HomeFragment(), false);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2) {
                        //switchFragment(new AboutFragment(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 3) {
                        //switchFragment(new TemplesFragment(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 4) {
                        //switchFragment(new PagerAdapter(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 5) {
                        //switchFragment(new MemoriesFragment(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 6) {
                        //switchFragment(new EventsFragment(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 7) {
                        //switchFragment(new VideosFragment(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 8) {
                        //switchFragment(new PhotosFragment(), true);
                    } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 9) {
                        //switchFragment(new FeedbackFragment(), true);
                    }
                    result.setSelectionByIdentifier(drawerItem.getIdentifier(), false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();*/
    }

    private void setToolbar()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        mtoolar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }

    private void setNavigationDrawer() {
        dLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
              //  Fragment frag = null;

                int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

                if (itemId == R.id.home_item) {
               //     frag = new Fragment1();
                }
                else if (itemId == R.id.about_app) {
                   // frag = new Fragment2();
                }

              /*  if (frag != null) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag);
                    transaction.commit();
                    dLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }*/

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        String btnName = null;
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                btnName = "Settings";
                break;
            case R.id.action_help:
                btnName = "Help";
                break;
            case R.id.about_zenica:
                btnName="About Zenica";
        }
        System.out.print(btnName);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

navigation_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
app:itemTextColor="#333"
app:itemIconTint="#333"
app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

navigation_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/home_item"
        android:title="Home"
       />
    <item android:id="@+id/cars"
        android:title="New Cars"
       />
    <item android:id="@+id/test_drive"
        android:title="Book A Test Drive"
       />
    <item android:id="@+id/locations"
        android:title="Our Locations"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/sell"
        android:title="Sell A Car"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/pay_bill"
        android:title="Pay Bills"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/about_zenica"
        android:title="About Zenica"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:title="Connect"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/about_app"
        android:title="About App"
        />
</group>

</menu>
```

Comment: set break point, attach debugger and let us know app crash at which line also post logcat if possible.

Comment: Make sure you have included `toolbar` layout in `navigation_drawer`, also post your error log cat

Comment: I guess u have not included toolbar in navigation_drawer

Comment: Yes adding toolbar in navigation_drawer helped. Now there is no error in logcat but i can't see my navigation drawer items

Comment: @Neha What problem you are facing in Navigation View ?